# Insert comma separated values in single column of mysql table using c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have many fields which has comma separated values in it.
I have to insert them in my MySql table

```
homeToSchool[0] = "Name";
homeToSchool[1] = "Mumbai, 400080, India";
homeToSchool[2] = "Malad, MG";

var cmdText ="INSERT INTO schoolschedule(Name, From, To) VALUES (@Name, @From, @To)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", homeToSchool[0]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@From", homeToSchool[1]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To", homeToSchool[2]);
connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am getting error due to comma separated values.

Comment: What is the actual error? Does it say "you can't insert comma-separated values", or perhaps something else, for example an error near ", "?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I bet the error message is this:

> *"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'From, To) VALUES.."*

Actually the problem is not with the value. It's on the column name you used and you didn't escape causing syntax error.

`FROM` and `TO` are reserved keywords. They can still be used provided that you wrapp them with backticks.

```
INSERT INTO schoolschedule(Name, `From`, `To`) VALUES (@Name, @From, @To)
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

If you have chance to alter the table, change the column name which is not a reserved keyword. This will avoid you from getting problems in the future.

Comment: +1 for writing error message `:D`

Comment: @SonerGönül that is the usual error message for syntax error `:)`